# Is it possible to get a "view" of the Acitivity stacks for all apps on an Android device programmatically?

Tags: android, android-activity

I wonder if it is possible to get a data representation of which applications are running and how their activity stacks are managed.

For instance I would like to know information such that:
App A is in the foreground with Activities 1,2,3. Activity 3 is displayed.
App B is in the background with Activities 1.
App C is a Service in the background.

Can I retrieve this information programmatically in a convenient way?
Do I need some special permission to do this? (System app?)

The most important info for me is to know which app is in the forground really...

Comment: Newer versions of Android take steps to help prevent you from determining what is in the foreground, for privacy reasons.

Comment: Even for system apps?

Comment: Yes you can; you cannot know which activity is active in a certain process without performing extensive bookkeeping; you cannot retrieve it conveniently, you do need special permissions to do this. You cannot know the foreground app/activity either way. The permission you need is the `vendor key` as you need to sign your apps with it, AND place them in a special part of the android OS/sdk/image on your device.